# How to detect Unix terminal character encoding?

Tags: java, linux, macos, encoding, console

Is there a way to detect the character encoding set in the terminal which is calling my Java program? In Windows I can call the "chcp" tool and parse the output.

But what about in Linux or Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Check the [locale(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locale) man page

You can change this by setting the LANG environment variable

```
$ export LANG=en_US.iso88591

$ locale
LANG=en_US.iso88591
LC_CTYPE="en_US.iso88591"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.iso88591"
LC_TIME="en_US.iso88591"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.iso88591"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.iso88591"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.iso88591"
LC_PAPER="en_US.iso88591"
LC_NAME="en_US.iso88591"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.iso88591"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.iso88591"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.iso88591"
```

LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.iso88591"

Comment: Better than nothing...the problem is that locale gives the same output even after changing the terminal encoding... it simply gives the default console encoding for new consoles...

Answer (score 1):

There is no defined communication path from the terminal app to processes running inside a terminal window (short of those defined by the terminal being emulated, such as window size changes). This would be true on any other Unix-like OS as well. Environment variables can only be inherited when a process starts. Looking at the values of these environment variables is all you can do.

Do you really expect people to be changing the encoding while a terminal window is open?  I can't imagine this is a common use case at all.